Discrepancy between lists of unanswered questions
If one clicks on "Unanswered" as shown in the figure below

one gets a list of questions with no upvoted or accepted answers. But questions with only downvoted answers don't appear in this list. Can anyone explain why?
The curious fact is that, if one clicks on "Questions" and then on "unanswered" as shown in the images, then questions with only downvoted answers appear in the list. I wonder which is the reason of this discrepancy.



Have you tried if this happens on other SE sites as well? I suspect it's not a prerogative of italian.SE.

@martina: I've observed the same behaviour on French.SE.

@martina: I think that the problem is that questions which are in the second list but not in the first one remain unperceived and thus unanswered for a long time.

You have stumbled upon a hilarious and weird quirk of the Stack Exchange engine.
One of those tabs shows questions that have no answers at all. The other shows questions that have no upvoted answers.
This has been confounding people since the dawn of time.

In both lists one finds questions with answers, but the questions with downvoted answers appear only in one of these two lists.

The problem is that questions which are in the second list but not in the first one remain unperceived and thus unanswered for a long time.
